# Parallelogram with vertices $\mathbf{0}$,$\mathbf{Xa}$,$\mathbf{Xb}$,$\mathbf{Xa+Xb}$ ($\mathbf{X}$ matrix, $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ vectors)

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, matrices, geometry, trigonometry

There is a paralellogram with vertices $\mathbf{0}$, $\mathbf{a}$, $\mathbf{b}$, and $\mathbf{a+b}$, whose area is $34$. What is the area of the parallelogram which has vertices $\mathbf{0}$, $\mathbf{Xa}$, $\mathbf{Xb}$, and $\mathbf{Xa+Xb}$, where

$$\mathbf{X}=\begin{pmatrix} 3 & -5 \\ -1 & -3 \end{pmatrix}.$$

Note: $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ are vectors.

I know that the paralellogram with vertices $\mathbf{0}$, $\mathbf{a}$, $\mathbf{b}$, and $\mathbf{a+b}$ has area:

$\operatorname{Area}^2$ = $\|a\|^2 \|b\|^2 - (a \cdot b)^2 = 34^2$, but how do I go from there and complete the problem?

Comment: do you know how to find the determinant of a matrix? Also, you will want to use the fact the area is the det(A) where A is the matrix.

Comment: @ForrestChanningHunter The determinant of a matrix is det(A) = ad-bc for the matrix \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}.

Comment: consider the following matrix $\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
0 & x_{a} \\ 
 x_{b}&x_{a} +x_{b}
\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$

Comment: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Volume_and_Jacobian_determinant

Comment: @ForrestChanningHunter Does that mean you are asking me for the determinant for the matrix? If so, the determinant of the matrix you posted is: -x_a*x_b.

Comment: @ForrestChanningHunter EDIT: I solved the problem. Thanks.